# Why do some images have third dimension 3 while others have 4?

Tags: python, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I don't have much knowledge of image processing. I am trying to implement a ConvNet. I downloaded some images as data set and made their  height and width equal. Then I tried loading them into np.array by this code:

```
train_list = glob.glob('A:\Code\Machine 
Learning\CNN\ConvolutionalNN1\TrainImg\*.jpg')
X_train_orig = np.array([np.array(Image.open(file)) for file in train_list])
```

But it gave me error that cannot broadcast (420,310) to (420,310,3). Then I printed the shape of array, some were (420,310,3) others (410,320,4). Why is so? And how can I change that to fit it in array?

Comment: The alpha value of RGBA

Comment: To drop the fourth dimension, `img[:, :, :3]`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq where should I write that? and there are not four but three elements in the tuple of shape. so what fourth dimensiopn are you refering to

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Problem

So basically what is happening over here is you are playing with three different formats of images (at least those that appear in your question). They are respectively:

- [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) (of dimension
  `(420, 310, 3)`), *three channels*
- [RGB-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) (of dimension
  `(420, 310, 4)`), *four channels*
- [Grayscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale)  (of dimension
  `(420, 310)`), *single channel*

The third dimension that you are seeing is what represents the number of channels in your image (the first two being the height and width respectively).

An example will further clear it up. I downloaded random images from the internet each belonging to one of the three formats mentioned above.

RGB image `dog.png`

[image]

RGB-A image `fish.png`

[image]

Grayscale image `lena.png`

[image]

Here's a python script to load each of them using `PIL` and display their shape:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

dog = Image.open('dog.png')
print('Dog shape is ' + str(np.array(dog).shape))

fish = Image.open('fish.png')
print('Fish shape is ' + str(np.array(fish).shape))

lena = Image.open('lena.png')
print('Lena shape is ' + str(np.array(lena).shape))
```

And here is the output:

```
Dog shape is (250, 250, 3)
Fish shape is (501, 393, 4)
Lena shape is (512, 512)
```

Hence, when you are trying to iteratively assign all the images to an array (`np.array`), you are getting the shape mis-match error.

### Solution

The easiest way to resolve this is to convert all the images to one particular format before saving it in the array. Assuming you will be using a pre-trained ImageNet model, we will convert them to `RGB` format (you can similarly choose a format of your choice also).

We will convert `RGB-A` to `RGB` using the following code:

```
fish = Image.open('fish.png')
print('Fish RGB-A shape is ' + str(np.array(fish).shape))
rgb = fish.convert('RGB')
print('Fish RGB shape is ' + str(np.array(rgb).shape))
```

Output is:

```
Fish RGB-A shape is (501, 393, 4)
Fish RGB shape is (501, 393, 3)
```

Similarly you can do for all your images, and then you have a consistent number of channels (*three* in this case) for all your images.

**NOTE**: In my example, the spatial dimensions vary for the images also. In your case that is not an issue as all are of consistent dimension `(420, 310)`.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: But does removing the alpha parameter affect the images in any way, as in they become blurry or something?

Comment: and i have another doubt that I just used *.jpg in glob, but the png images are getting automatically converted to jpg and are being selected. is that normal and ok or should i manually convert them to png and then select?

Comment: Regarding your first question, it depends on your use case. Quoting from Wiki, the *alpha* channel defines **how opaque each pixel is and allows an image to be combined over others using alpha compositing, with transparent areas and anti-aliasing of the edges of opaque regions.** If you are going to use the images for classification or something, it can be safely removed without much consequence, if using trained models.

Comment: And regarding your second query, that is not the expected behavior of **glob.glob**. Documentation can be found over here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob It will recursively select files only that match the format `*.jpg`. The mistake is occurring somewhere else I feel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent problem solver descriptive answer! :-)